# line associated with tikz \draw operation is not obscured by objects on \backgroundpath of new shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

I don't have much experience with creating new symbols using the \pgfdeclareshape macro, and I believe there are a few things I'm overlooking.

My specific question is:  Why the line associated with the tikz \draw operation is not obscured by the symbol when placed on a path?  For instance, in many examples of the circuits library documentation, resistors are clearly not drawn with a line extending through the center of the symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{symbol shape}
{
\anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
\backgroundpath{%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-2cm}{-0.5cm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-2cm}{0.5cm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2cm}{0.5cm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2cm}{-0.5cm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-2cm}{-0.5cm}}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-2cm}{-0.5cm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2cm}{0.5cm}}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-2cm}{0.5cm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2cm}{-0.5cm}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
}
\makeatother


\begin{tikzpicture}[
circuit,
circuit declare symbol=symbol,
set symbol graphic={shape=symbol shape, draw, minimum size=1cm,transform shape}
]
\draw (0,0) to [symbol] (8,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone suggest an improvement to the code shown above in order to prevent the \draw operation line from extending through the symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TikZ doesn’t know where the lines should start and end. You haven’t defined a border or any anchors besides the `center` one.

When we base our shape on `rectangle ee` we get all the properties of the `rectangle` shape plus the `input` and `output` anchors that are additionally defined for `rectangle ee`.

The size of the rectangle (`2cm x .5cm`) is based on `\tikzcircuitssizeunit` (initially `7pt`) via the `circuit symbol size` style. Now the rectangle scales properly with all other circuit shape options. The `resistor`’s default setting is `width 4 height 1`. For the sizes `2cm x .5cm` the value is `width 8.12936 height 2.03233`.

Of course, if the shape should always have the same size you can use `minimum width=2cm, minimum height=.5cm`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits,circuits.ee.IEC}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{symbol shape}{%
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle ee]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{south east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{input}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{output}
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle ee]
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=rectangle ee]
  \behindbackgroundpath{%
    \pgf@process{\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}%
    \pgf@xa\pgf@x\pgf@ya\pgf@y
    \pgf@process{\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}%
    \pgf@xb\pgf@x\pgf@yb\pgf@y
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}%
  }
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  circuit declare symbol=symbol,
  set symbol graphic={
    shape=symbol shape,
    draw,
    transform shape,
    circuit symbol size=width 8.12936 height 2.03233,
%    circuit symbol size=width 4 height 1,% standard value for an resistor
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\draw (0,0) to [symbol] (3,0) to [resistor] (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, this is what I wanted to achieve.  Your pointing out that a border is needed makes sense.